# Converting Uppercase to Lowercase using char

Tags: java

```
package letter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Letter {
static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ch;
        System.out.println("Enter uppercase letter: ");
        ch=input.next();
       System.out.print(upperCaseToLowerCase(ch));<---got it wrong here...why??? and how????
    }
    public static char upperCaseToLowerCase(char ch){

        char Variable=Character.toLowerCase(ch);
        return ch;


    }

}
```

Comment: "got it wrong here" doesn't give any indication of what is wrong. Please be more specific in future. But look at the declaration of `ch` in `main` compared with the type that your `upperCaseToLowerCase` method requires...

Comment: String::toUpperCase? https://processing.org/reference/String_toUpperCase_.html

Comment: well for one thing you return the unmodified ch value, instead of the newly created `Variable` value. First of all, make the variable name lower case. Second of all, return that variable instead of ch. Secondly, make sure your types match.

Comment: Also you will like to return Variable instead of ch in the upperCaseToLowerCAse method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing you method with this,

```
public static char upperCaseToLowerCase(char ch){

ch = ch.toLowerCase();
return ch;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1) you are passing String but your method argument is char type.

use

```
System.out.print(upperCaseToLowerCase(ch.charAt(0)));
```

2) return `Variable` instead of `ch`

```
return Variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

change `character` to `String`

```
public static String upperCaseToLowerCase(String ch){

    return ch.toLowerCase();



}
```

or pass `character` argument

```
char ch1 = ch.charAt(0);
System.out.println(upperCaseToLowerCase(ch1));
```